# How to call android functions in a custom plugin in cordova project?

Tags: javascript, java, android, cordova, plugins

I am new to the cordova plugin development stuff. I want to write a custom plugin which is able to call functions from an android studio project in cordova project. I follow [this](https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-hello) tutorial and it works, but instead of the hello world result, I want to call functions and activities of my android studio project and get the results in the cordova project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can call any functions like regular function in java. and to call other activities syntax is

```
cordova.startActivityForResult(this, ringtone, 0);
```

after that to get the result call `onActivityResult` cordova will by default call `onActivityResult` from the same class you called `startActivityForResult`

have a look at my plugin's source file

https://github.com/vasani-arpit/cordova-plugin-RingtoneSelector/blob/master/src/android/RingtoneSelector.java

Comment: Plz I'm new on this, I didn't get it. how did you call this plugin on your cordova project ? I have an android project, and i want to integrate it in a plugin, and call the functions from the cordova project.

Comment: you need to create a plugin using plugman.add android platform and you should be good to go.
but keep in mind that you must know the basic of andoid.
here is a link to I think can help up and running with plugman http://itsmycodeshare.blogspot.in/2016/01/create-custom-cordova-plugins-using.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i this you didn't understand very much my problem. I have already created a plugin that contain a java file that return a string, and i get this result on a cordova project, but now i have an external android project, and i can't call his functions on the plugin, and I didn't understand how I make the binding between it ( the external android project ) and the cordova project through the js file in the plugin

Comment: first create a plugin (which you already did). then create a cordova project and install that plugin into it using `cordova plugin add <path>` if all works great then you will be able to use syntax as `cordova-plugin-hello`'s readme.md, `hello.greet("World", success, failure);`

Comment: thank you, but i already did this, i was questioning about haw integrate an android studio project into that plugin, so I can call functions of the android project into cordova.

Comment: when you installed plugin and create a android platform its is already added in `project/platforms/android/` directory. just open that directory in android studio, both the codes will be there. (plugin's and www's)

Comment: Thank you, i'll try right now, thank you for your answers